# SQL Server query to filter rows doesn't contain a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with `IDCourse` and `IDProvince` columns; a course can be imparted in different provinces. I would like to get all the `IDCourse` values that are not imparted in a given `ProvinceID`.

For example.

```
IDCourse     IDProvince
------------------------
   1        100
   1        102
   1        105
   2        100
   2        108
   3        109
   3        107
   4        100
   4        105
   4        106
   5        102
   5        108
```

I would like to get all course are not imparted on the `IDProvince = 100`, so the result would be just the `IDCourse` 3 and 5

I could do a simple query like

```
Select IDCourse 
from MyTable 
Where IDCourse not in (Select IDCourse 
                       From Mytable
                       Where IDProvince = 100)
```

But I want to optimize it, is there any other way I can do this query? By the way this is just an example, the query in fact is bigger.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "...not in ( Select DISTINCT IDCourse ... )"  ?

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti: Does that really matter? Doesn't SQL Server optimize better than that?!?

Comment: I just said is an example, the query itself has a lot of joins, so didnt want to reapeat the block...

Answer (score 0):

Two other ways to achieve the same results that *might* give equal or better performance is to use either `not exists` or `except`:

Using `not exists` (should give the exact same execution plan as using `not in`:

```
SELECT IDCourse FROM MyTable m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Mytable
    WHERE IDProvince = 100
    AND idcourse = m.idcourse
)
```

Using `except` should give a slightly different execution plan (and performs slightly better on the sample data - but I wouldn't draw any conclusions from that given the limited size of the sample):

```
SELECT IDCourse FROM MyTable 
EXCEPT
SELECT IDCourse FROM MyTable WHERE IDProvince = 100
```

I can't tell you if any of the queries will perform better, it depends on indexing and other factors, so try for yourself and see :)

Comment: but Except is not the same as NOT IN?

Comment: @user2112420 It not exactly the same as it operates on sets, but it will give the same result (without duplicates though).

Answer (score 0):

> in order to optimize it - by using variable the sql server use the
>   same cache plan no matter the input in IDProvince. just change the
>   variable

```
 DECLARE @IDProvince int
    SELECT  IDCourse   
    FROM tbl
    WHERE IDCourse NOT IN (SELECT IDCourse 
                       FROM tbl 
                       WHERE IDProvince=@IDProvince)
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: in order to optimize it - by using variable the sql server use the same cache plan no matter the input in IDProvince. just change the variable

Comment: Thanks! It would be even better if you edited the explanation into your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this fits into your larger query (since we do not have that code), but it could be as simple as:

```
SELECT IDCourse
FROM TABLE
WHERE IDProvince <> 100
GROUP BY IDCourse
```

Or did I miss something in your question?